# Sync locally only last 30 days of mail

Tags: email, mutt, offlineimap

I have offlineimap set up with my gmail account to sync my mail locally via imap. It works great.

Is there a way to only sync the last 30 days worth of mail?

I've looked into archivemail but it looks like for imap mailboxes it will archive or delete not only the mail locally but on the server.

Ideally the end result I want is to only see the last 30 days worth of activity in mutt.

Can I use offlineimap or archivemail or another application to archive or delete only the local mail I have that is older the 30 days?

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please can you mark it as "correct"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `maxage` parameter should do what you want:

```
[Account my-account]
localrepository = ...
remoterepository = ...
maxage = 30
```